# remove a presentModalViewController

Tags: tabbar, viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

i have posted how to show a modalViewController but now i need to remove it and come back to my tabbarController with the view he was. thx

Answer (score 11):

From within the modalViewController

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: It's not working for me. (I've presented the modal view controller from  a tabBarController)

Comment: I dont think my answer was right actually. The modal controller dismisses itself. If you have a class for it just call self dismissModal...

Comment: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: is deprecated since iOS 6.0. Use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] from now on.